# How do I completely block Google DNS servers?

Tags: arch-linux, dns

Previously I've used Unbound as a DNS resolver, but whenever I checked on dnsleaktest.com I got results for Google DNS only. Then moving to systemd-resolved fixed that issue. Now I'm using pdnsd, and that issue has showed up again.

I've blocked Google DNS server from /etc/hosts, added them to reject list in pdnsd.conf also blocked them from my router then how come they are still accessible?

Comment: "blocked Google DNS server from /etc/hosts" ... how that does that even work? O.o

Comment: @muru by adding the entries with localhosts?

Comment: What entries would you add to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could make a manual route like:

```
8.0.0.0/8 accessible via 192.168.0.254 (Or some other IP that is not a router)
```

That would mean, that your device would try to get to 8.8.8.8 via 192.168.0.254, but this device either is non-existent or is not a router, so you cant get to 8.8.8.8 this way.

On Linux you might achieve it with this command. Replace eth0 with proper device name, check with "ip a" command.

```
ip route add 8.0.0.0/8 via 192.168.0.254 dev eth0
```

I have no idea if this will make anything important inaccessible. Some examples for ip route command: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-configuring-default-route-with-ipcommand/

Comment: Blocking a /8 does not seem a particularly good idea.

Comment: Can there be a route to 1 address? like 8.8.8.8